# jQuery Image Delete Confirmation Message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Firstly, my sincere apologies because I'm not very well versed with JavaScript and some may feel this a foolish post, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm currently using the script below to delete gallery images.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        Galleria.ready(function() {
            this.$('thumblink').click();

        $(".galleria-image").append( 
        "<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
        $(".btn-delete").live("click", function(){  
        var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); 
        $.msgbox("You are about to delete this image. It cannot be restored at a later date. Do you wish to continue?", {
        type: "alert",
          buttons : [
            {type: "submit", value: "Delete"},
            {type: "cancel", value: "Cancel"}
          ]
          },
          function(result) {
          if(result)


          // send the AJAX request
          $.ajax({
            url : 'delete.php',
            type : 'post',
            data : { image : img.attr('src'),  idnum: "VALUE", lid: "VALUE"},
            success : function(){
            img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });               
    });
        return false;
    });     
});

</script>
```

I've now find a more suitable jQuery confirmation script [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/) which I'd now like to try and implement.

Using the `script.js` file from this site and my existing script, I've tried to combine them and have come up with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
Galleria.ready(function() {
    this.$('thumblink').click();
    $(".galleria-image").append( 
    "<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
    $('.btn-delete').click(function(){
    var elem = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find('.item'); 
        $.confirm({
            'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
            'message'   : 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
            'buttons'   : {
                'Yes'   : {
                    'class' : 'blue',
                    'action': function(){
                        elem.slideUp();
                              $.ajax({
                                url : 'delete.php',
                                type : 'post',
                                data : { image : img.attr('src'),  idnum: "VALUE", lid: "VALUE"},
                                success : function(){
                                img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
                                }
                            }); 

                    }
                },
                'No'    : {
                    'class' : 'gray',
                    'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
                }
                }
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

The problem I'm having is that although the page loads, it doesn't load in the default `Gallery` image format, and the `trash icon` which I use as a visual trigger to delete the image has disappeared at the bottom of each image.

I've gone into the JavaScript Console and the error it shows is:`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`highlighting this line in my code as the problem: `$.confirm({` but I have to be honest and say I'm not really sure what this means.

I've tried quite a few variations of changing the code around to try and get this to work, unfortunately without success.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly take a look at this please and provide some guidance on where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

**Working solution**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
Galleria.ready(function() {
this.$('thumblink').click();
$(".galleria-image").append( 
"<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
$('.btn-delete').click(function(){
var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find('img'); 
    $.confirm({
        'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
        'message'   : 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
        'buttons'   : {
            'Yes'   : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                'action': function(){
                    //elem.slideUp();
                          $.ajax({
                            url : 'delete.php',
                            type : 'post',
                            data : { image : img.attr('src'),  idnum: "VALUE", lid: "VALUE"},
                            success : function(){
                            img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
                            }
                        }); 

                }
            },
            'No'    : {
                'class' : 'gray',
                'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
                 }
               }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link to the page you're working on, or put a test case on jsFiddle.net ?

Comment: Hi @kennis, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I've added a link to a test page in my original post. Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some braces, It cant be really solution to the problem but first check with this code, I have formatted with necessary braces and let us know your findings:

```
Galleria.ready(function() {
this.$('thumblink').click();
$(".galleria-image").append( 
"<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
$('.btn-delete').click(function(){
var elem = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find('.item'); 
    $.confirm({
        'title'     : 'Delete Confirmation',
        'message'   : 'You are about to delete this item. <br />It cannot be restored at a later time! Continue?',
        'buttons'   : {
            'Yes'   : {
                'class' : 'blue',
                'action': function(){
                    elem.slideUp();
                          $.ajax({
                            url : 'delete.php',
                            type : 'post',
                            data : { image : img.attr('src'),  idnum: "VALUE", lid: "VALUE"},
                            success : function(){
                            img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
                            }
                        }); 

                }
            },
            'No'    : {
                'class' : 'gray',
                'action': function(){}  // Nothing to do in this case. You can as well omit the action property.
                 }
               }
            });
        });
    });
```

Also Your success callfunction is missing `data` parameter

Comment: Hi @user1042031, thank you very much for this. This brings back the `Gallery` format and the `trash` icon, but unfortunately, when I click on the icon, nothing happens. I thought, perhaps wrongly that `$.ajax` function would take care of the on click event. Kind regards

Comment: Ok, SO now are you able to see the delete confirmation?As i said in my anwser your ajax success call back function is wrong it should be like `success : function(response){}`.

Comment: Hi @user1042031, thank you for getting back to me so quickly. Unfortunately, no I don't see the `confirmation message`. In fact when I've reloaded the page the same issues i.e. the incorrect gallery format and missing `deletion` icon have reoccurred.

Comment: You may have edited the code again Copy the script in to notepadd ++ and check for the braces closing

Comment: Hi, my apologies, I'd missed a line off the code. I've now added the code you kindly provided, and the page format and deletion image have now returned. However, when I click on the delete icon nothing happens. I've been into the JavaScript console and I receive the following error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'confirm' 
(anonymous function)
f.event.dispatch
f.event.add.h.handle.i`

Thank you for your help. Kind regards

Comment: i think the error is quite clear are you missing anything in your php `gallery.php`...??

Comment: Hi @user1042031. Thank you for your continued help and patience :) I've gone back to the script, tidied it up and I can now get the confirmation message to appear. The `No` button works fine, but sadly when I click the `Yes` nothing happens. Using the JavaScript console I receive this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: img is not defined`, pointing to this line in my code: `$(".galleria-image").append(`  Kind regards

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13886/discussion-between-user1042031-and-irhm)

Comment: With some very minor alterations from the solution posted by &user1042031, I've been able to get this to work. I've have posted the working solution in my original post. Kind regards

Comment: Hi @user1042031, I just wanted to say thank you for all your time , trouble and patience with this. It really is greatly appreciated. All the best and kind regards